# Paypal Buttons Behaving Differently based on Email Program

Tags: email, paypal, paypal-buttons

I am using paypal buttons created with the paypal Button creation tool.  The button is embedded in an html email, sent to a user.

If I open the email in its native email program (yahoo, gmail, etc.) - the button redirects to the correct page and payment can be made.

If I open the email in Apple Mail, the button takes me to the login screen, or my account if I happen to be logged in.

I've checked to make sure I have copied the button EXACTLY, just not sure why the behavior is different or if there is anything I can do to ensure the right redirection behavior.

Comment: This *might* be a security feature in Apple Mail. Can you add some more detail - show the desired URL, the form's code, and the URL you end up on in Apple Mail?

Comment: <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="KWVRTZCVRP5RC">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

Comment: @Pekka웃 - if I click on it in yahoo or gmail, the link takes me to a screen with a description, amount and login option.  If I click on it in apple mail, it takes me to the home page of paypal.

Comment: Can you edit the code in the question? - I can't get the form to redirect me to a screen with description, amount and login option, either, when running it in a browser. Not sure why.

Comment: @Pekka - its the exact code from PayPal Button Creation Tool.  They recommend NOT modifying it.  I think it must be a setting in the Apple Mail program, but I sure can't find it.  Its not passing the hidden hosted button id I think.

Comment: Right. I don't know what the problem could be... there would be one workaround: linking to a HTML page that contains the button, instead of having the button show up in the E-Mail itself. Would be an added click, though